# javascript loop getting scores

Tags: javascript, loops

I was hoping maybe I could get some guidance or check if it is even possible to do the following: I need to get scores based on user input. user input can be from 90 to 292... the score starts at 34 and increments by 1 based on the input. I have a table to reference the scores. It seems there is a pattern on the score sheet that is why I was thinking a loop may work. if not I will be writing close to 100 if statements... the pattern is this:

```
sum     &    score
90      =    34
91-92   =    35
93-94   =    36
95      =    37
96-97   =    38
98-99   =    39
100     =    40
```

For every 5 on the sum the score increments by 3.. I think that is probably doable with the loop, but how could I catch the numbers in between?? Here is what I've tried, but I can't seem to find the logic on this one.

```
var sum = 125;

var start = 90;
var finish = 292;
var score_start = 34;

for(var i=start; i<=finish; i++){

    if(sum == $start){
        score = score_start;
    }       

}
```

Thank you for your feedback,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion from `sum` to `score` is covered by a simple formula:

```
var score = Math.round(sum * 0.6) - 20;
```

This can be turned into a function as follows:

```js
var getScore = sum => Math.round(sum * 0.6) - 20;

for (var i = 90; i <= 100; i++) {
  console.log(i + ': ' + getScore(i));
}

console.log(292 + ': ' + getScore(292));
```

Comment: does it go inside the loop?

Comment: See my edit. You can use it in a loop if that's what you require.

Comment: You said it increased by 3 for every 5 increments of sum, therefore it is a [linear relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation). After that, you work out the slope of the function (`3 / 5` or `0.6`) and then work out what to add/subtract to get 34 from 90 (-20 in this case).

Comment: Thank you so much! no need for the loop I just needed the score var score = Math.round(sum * 0.6) - 20; that is enough! I wish I knew that much math! thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this even without loop, if you objective is to calculate the final score.
Steps------

Calculate the difference between sum and start, let say x.

Divide x by 5  let say y

Multiply y with 3 and add it to 34

Now calculate  x%5 let say z

If z is zero then answer is fine

If z is 1-2 then add 1 in answer

If z in between 3-4 add 2 in answer